# Space between columns in bootstrap, last column jumps to the next row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with bootstrap. I would like to set 1% space between columns. If I set it like in code below the last column jumps to the next row.

HTML

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3  border">
        <span class="cell-name">MaxCom MM720BB</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3  border">
        <span class="cell-name">MaxCom MM822 black</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 border">
        <span class="cell-name">Goclever Quantum 2 400</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 border">
        <span class="cell-name">Nokia 230</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid #cdcccc;
    margin: 0px 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, when adding a margin, it adds to the width of that element. This extra width will bump the last col-lg-3 down to the next row.

Instead, what you can do is add another div inside the col-lg-3, and place a border on that. So, something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="border">
        <span class="cell-name">MaxCom MM720BB</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="border">
        <span class="cell-name">MaxCom MM822 black</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="border">
        <span class="cell-name">Goclever Quantum 2 400</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="border">
        <span class="cell-name">Nokia 230</span>
        <div class="tel">
        </div>
        <span class="price-tel">1zł</span>
        <span class="vat-tel">(1,23 z VAT)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid #cdcccc;
}
```

Comment: Man u saved me a lot of time. THANK U VERY MUCH.